# Problems with creating session in the view

Tags: python, django

How to do that the same session but for each room, not for all of the rooms. In this case when this part working if user.has_perm('pass_perm', room) it creating this session                        request.session['joined'] = True but this works for all of the rooms

```
views.py
def auth_join(request, room, uuid):
room = get_object_or_404(Room, invite_url=uuid)
if request.session.get('joined', False):
    join_room(request,uuid)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(Room.get_absolute_url(room))
else:
    try:
        room_type = getattr(Room.objects.get(invite_url=uuid), 'room_type')
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404
    if room_type == 'private':
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user = request.user.username    
            form_auth = AuthRoomForm(request.POST)
            if form_auth.is_valid():
                try:
                    room_pass = getattr(Room.objects.get(invite_url=uuid), 'room_pass')
                except ValueError: 
                    raise Http404
                password2 = form_auth.cleaned_data.get('password2')
                if room_pass != password2:
                    messages.error(request, 'Doesn\'t match')
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())
                else:
                    user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=user)
                    try:
                        room = get_object_or_404(Room, invite_url=uuid)
                    except ValueError:
                        raise Http404

                    assign_perm('pass_perm',user, room)
                    if user.has_perm('pass_perm', room):
                        request.session['joined'] = True
                        join_room(request,uuid)
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(Room.get_absolute_url(room))
                    else:
                        return HttpResponse('Problem issues')
        else:
            form_auth = AuthRoomForm()
        return render(request,'rooms/auth_join.html', {'form_auth':form_auth})
    else:
        try:
            room = get_object_or_404(Room, invite_url=uuid)
        except ValueError:
            raise Http404
        join_room(request,uuid)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(Room.get_absolute_url(room))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the session key to something unique and identifiable to the room.

```
if user.has_perm('pass_perm', room):
    join_key = f"joined_{room.pk}"
    request.session[join_key] = True
    join_room(request, uuid)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(Room.get_absolute_url(room))
```

Comment: thanks, also do you know how to add expire date to that, for example after week session will become False

Comment: You'll want to use `request.sessions.set_expiry() as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views)

Comment: when i am doing that it takes every session, not only this one, and logout me and so on, do you know how to do that exacly in this case?

Comment: I mistakenly said request.sessions where it should have been request.session (singular). So request.session.set_expiry(608400) will set the current session to expire after 1 week. 608400 = number of seconds in a week. All other sessions will retain the default expiry time.

Comment: i tried, but it logout me again after expiring, what is wrong here?)

Comment: This has deviated quite a bit from your original question. You should ask a new question with your current issue.